# Php curl и браузер тор

Tags: php

Подключаюсь к сайтам через curl использую прокси тор.
Но прокси работают только при условии что браузер тор запущен, при его закрытии прокси перестают работать.
Как сделать чтоб работали прокси если я закрою браузер тор

Answer (score 1):

Установить tor отдельно, а не в составе tor-браузера. Запустить его в режиме демона (в настройках проверить/указать адрес и порт).
Затем пропустить curl через tor (адрес и порт приведены условно, в кач-ве примера):
`curl --socks5-hostname localhost:5555 http://ya.ru/` (curl старше версии 7.18.0)
или
`curl -x socks5h://localhost:5555 http://www.google.com/` (на версиях старше 7.21.7)
Параметры вызова curl непосредственно из php надо поискать аналогичные.
Ещё можно прописать в `${HOME}/.curlrc` настройку вида `socks5 = localhost:5555`
или добавить переменные окружения среды:
`http_proxy=socks5h://localhost:5555` и `https_proxy=socks5ya.ruh://localhost:5555`
Если нужен HTTP прокси в кач-е прослойки перед tor - обычно используется связка tor+privoxy.
Цепочки в tor, запущенном в режиме демона, можно менять, посылая команду `signal NEWNYM` через telnet (вручную или скриптом).